# Call to a member function bind_param() on bool en una sentencia SQL que si ejecuta en el DBMS

Tags: mysql, mysqli, php7

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en PHP y en el login estoy recibiendo el problema de **Call to a member function bind_param() on bool** y no tengo ni idea por que me arroja este error en mi codigo

```
function insertUser($user) {
        $instance = Connection::getInstance();
        $conn = $instance->getConnection();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (username, password) VALUES (?,?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user->getUsername(), $user->getPassword());
        $stmt->execute();
        $conn->close();
    }
```

Se que el error aparece por que en el prepare() el query tenga problemas de logica y no funcione, pero este mismo query lo tengo en una conexion Java a Mysql y dentro del propio Mysql funciona

Comment: En el `$stmt->exec()` tienes dos `$$` y cambia `exec()` por `execute()`

Comment: Ya corregi ese error, sin embargo, sigo obteniendo el mismo error, en un principio pensé que era problema del Hasher que estoy usando, pues cambie los parámetros con los que iba a trabajar y el tamaño del Hash de la contraseña era mayor al maximo que la base de datos me aceptaba, pero modifique la base de datos para aceptar un string de mayor longitud